# Pythob-based Azure function cannot load UUID package?

Tags: python, azure-functions, uuid

I am using python-based Azure Function and would like to use the UUID package in the function.

However when the function is deployed, the function fails on the `import uuid` statement. uuid is specified in requirements and installs ok.

the uuid import works fine when I run the function locally in debug mode, but not when deployed.